# Making a new array based on an exploded array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to make a new array ($names) that is the same size of *$years* array. I'm looping through the $year variable, but struggling to double "Explode" the $years_names variable (first by comma then by colon), and not sure that's the best way to go. Also because of that, I'm not able to use search_array. Since it may not have data for each year, I'd like the new array to hold a null value in the position for that year. So in my $years_names variable, I am missing data from 2010 to 2012, so indexes 0-1 should be null, and index 8 since there is no data for that 2018 either. Attached is a more or less what I'm trying to get for my $names array. Thanks!

[image]

```
$years = range(2010, 2020);

$data_years = "2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020";
$data_names = "Charlie,Lucy,Linus,Pig Pen,Snoopy,Woodstock,Peppermint Patty,Marcie";

$years_names = "2012:Charlie,2013:Lucy,2014:Linus,2015:Pig Pen,2016:Snoopy,2017:Woodstock,2019:Peppermint Patty,2020:Marcie";
$Exploded = explode(',', $years_names);
$names = [];

foreach($Exploded as $i => $item) {
     $names[$i] = explode(':', $item);
    //echo "i= {$i}<br/>";
    //echo "item= {$item}<br/>";
    //echo $names[$i][0] . ':' . $names[$i][1] . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Why is your data in this format?

Comment: The data is supplied from an API call in this way. The $years and $names array is then used in a graphing chart, so I unfortunately need to work with how the data is supplied.

Comment: This is a very odd format to use, are you sure there isn't a different format the API can supply?

Comment: There are two additional outputs with the date and name values in a string list, but I still have the same problem of having to fill the $names array.

Comment: Edited the post to add the two other values $data_years and $data_name...unfortunately that's all I have.

Comment: Having `$data_years` and `$data_names` separate is useless because it seems that `$data_years` is generating more dates than there are names, so there is no way to tie a specific name to a specific year. If `$data_years` only contained years that correlate with `$data_names`, and was in the same order, would make the solution way easier.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton you're right...sorry about that, I was trying recreate production-like structure while removing data that shouldn't be posted outside of our company (hence the Peanuts characters). The data for names and years that comes out from the API call is 1:1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$years = range(2010, 2020);
$years_names = "2012:Charlie,2013:Lucy,2014:Linus,2015:Pig Pen,2016:Snoopy,2017:Woodstock,2019:Peppermint Patty,2020:Marcie";

//split `$years_names` at comma
$split_values = explode(',', $years_names);

//convert values to a more usable format
$split_values = array_reduce($split_values, function($return, $item) {
    
    //explode $item (e.g `2012:Charlie`) at the colon symbol
    $explode = explode(':', $item);
    
    //separate year from name as key => value
    $return[$explode[0]] = $explode[1];

    //this return reduces the current iteration of `$split_values` to the key=>value pair
    return $return;
});

$names = [];
foreach($years as $year) {
    
    //set default value as null. If year is not found in next loop, this will remain
    $names[$year] = null;
    
    //check if year exists in $split_values
    if(array_key_exists($year, $split_values)) {
        
        //if it does, set $names[$year] to that value
        $names[$year] = $split_values[$year];
    }
    
}

print_r($names);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [2010] => 
    [2011] => 
    [2012] => Charlie
    [2013] => Lucy
    [2014] => Linus
    [2015] => Pig Pen
    [2016] => Snoopy
    [2017] => Woodstock
    [2018] => 
    [2019] => Peppermint Patty
    [2020] => Marcie
)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll give it a go, but this makes things look much more clear. Thank you.